# Como validar si fecha existe mediante selects en Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

la siguiente consulta es acerca de como poder validar si la fecha que se selecciona existe, en este caso sea un año bisiesto, en mi formulario tengo 3 selects (DÍA - MES - AÑO) y el input de EDAD que se auto calcula con los datos seleccionados en los selects anteriores.

[image: 3 selects para día-mes-año]

Esta es mi función que uso para auto-calular la edad, mediante evento change tanto para AniCar,MesCar,DiaCar. La parte comentada en la función es lo que estaba probando pero solo me valida siempre y cuando seleccione el día:29, mes: febrero

```
$('#AniCar').change(function (){
                    if($('#AniCar').val()!=0 && $('#MesCar').val()!=0 && $('#DiaCar').val()!=0){
                        fecha    = new Date();
                        anioAct  = fecha.getFullYear();
                        mesAct   = fecha.getMonth()+1;
                        diaAct   = fecha.getDate();

                        Dianac = $('#DiaCar').val();
                        Mesnac = $('#MesCar').val();
                        Anonac = $('#AniCar option:selected').text();
                        var Edad = anioAct-Anonac;
                        if(mesAct<Mesnac){
                            Edad--;
                        }
                        if(mesAct==Mesnac){
                            if(diaAct<Dianac){Edad--;}
                        }
                        
                        /*if(Dianac == 29 && Mesnac == 2){
                            if (Anonac%4==0 && (Anonac%100!=0 || Anonac%400==0)){
                            $('#EdaCar').val(Edad);
                            return true;
                        } else{
                            $('#EdaCar').val('');
                            $('#DiaCar').val(0);
                            $('#MesCar').val(0);
                            $('#AniCar').val(0);
                            
                            alert('AÑO BISIESTO NO VALIDO');
                        }}*/

                        $('#EdaCar').val(Edad);
                    }else{
                        $('#EdaCar').val('');
                    }
                    
                    });
```

No sé si crear una función aparte para esa validacione de fecha bisiesta, ya que en el primer if solo hace la validacion que los datos que se obtengan sean diferente a 0 para hacer el cálculo o se puede hacer tal validación dentro de la misma función. De antemano, gracias por el apoyo a la espera de sus comentarios

Comment: `Anicar`, `MesCar`, `EdaCar`, `DiaCar`, `Dianac`, `Mesnac`,`DiaAct`. Recuerda que tu código generalmente será mantenido por otra persona, por lo tanto, vale la pena escoger nombres de variable que tengan sentido. `AnioActual`, `DiaNacimiento`, `DiaActual`, `MesNacimiento`. Nadie te va a penalizar por usar más de seis caracteres en el nombre de una variable. Más bien te lo van a agradecer

Comment: Gracias por la recomendación estimado, lo tendré en cuenta :)